# How can I center hr divider (in bootstrap 4)

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend, styling

How can i center the  hr divider? For some reason it is left aligned despite of text-center bootstrap class. Text before and after it is centered!
You can see it here: http://www.mokado.pl/index.html#about

```
<section class="about page-section bg-primary" id="about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-left">
          <div class="text col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h2 class="text-white mt-0">Mokado</h2>
            <hr class="divider light my-4 text-center" />
            <p class="text-white mb-4">
              Ideą marki Mokado jest połączenie estetyki i komfortu... 
            </p>
            <!-- <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#services"
              >Get Started!</a
            > -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this CSS on your `hr` tag

```
hr {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or you can use `mx-auto` class also, if you don't want write CSS

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a CSS style overwriting the bootstarp.

Add this at the end of your style sheet.

This line was already there `margin-top: 1.5rem !important;`

I added these two.

`margin-left: auto;`

`margin-right: auto;`

```
.mt-4, .my-4 {
    margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

See the screen shot.[image]

When I use the code you gave above I also see it centered.

[image]

Comment: do you know when you overwrite property that apply in all places, if he apply `margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto` in `.mt-4` whenever `.mt-4` is defined this css property apply on that. i think you dont know about bootstrap, there is also available class for above property, dont change it